# Regular Expression to Match 1 Character and Single or Double Digit in Any Order

Tags: c#, regex

I should probably state up front that my understanding of Regexs are very limited, I can do some very basic stuff but really struggle to write my own to match specific patterns.

I need to get the parts of some coordinates from a string. The coordinates can be in any order. So for instance my columns go from 1-15 and the rows from A-O and I want to retrieve the 2 parts separately but they could appear in the string in any order.

The Regex I have is as follows:

```
([A-Z]{1})([1-9]{1}[0-5]?)
```

This matches H12 but not 12H. It should also only allow numbers from 1-15 but currently allows numbers greater than that.

In case it makes a difference - I will be using this in c# .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `my columns go from 1-15 and the rows from A-O and I want to retrieve the 2 parts separately but they could appear in the string in any order.`

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:([A-O])([1-9]|1[0-5])|([1-9]|1[0-5])([A-O]))$
```

Comment: Thanks, that matches where I couldn't before but I now have a new problem in grabbing the results of the match. I'll have to create a new question for that.

Comment: Oh yes since you will be getting matches in 4 possible groups now.

Comment: I actually didn't need any further help in the end as I did a string.IsNullOrEmpty check and if true took the alternate group.